# Express Backend Application, destructure an array of objects and return new array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, javascript-objects, mern

I'm working with an api in a mern app, on the backend I would like to destructor the array of objects, run a function on an item each each of the arrays and return a new array of objects or add the new value to the array.
Here is my controller

```
const getObjects = async (req, res) => {
  const { bucketKey } = req.params
  const bucket = await new ForgeSDK.ObjectsApi().getObjects(
    bucketKey,
    req.params.objectName,
    req.oauth_client,
    req.oauth_token
  )
  const bucketObjects = bucket.body.items
  // const encodedUrn = urnify(objectKey)
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
    bucketObjects,
    totalObjects: bucketObjects.length,
    numOfPages: 1,
  })
}
```

So each item in the array of bucketObjects has an objectKey, I would like to take the objectKey convert it to a Base64-encoded string and create a new array of objects

Here is the response I am returning in postman

```
    "bucketObjects": [
        {
            "bucketKey": "dashboard",
            "objectKey": "BRISMETRO-BRM-ADLSTSO00-3DM-000020.ifc",
            "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:dashboard/BRISMETRO-BRM-ADLSTSO00-3DM-000020.ifc",
            "sha1": "4ed04b922c8863ac8323226da2a5f974730d13f0",
            "size": 937888,
            "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/dashboard/objects/BRISMETRO-BRM-ADLSTSO00-3DM-000020.ifc"
        },
```

Comment: well, transform items of the return array due to Your requirements ... ie: ` const resutlBuckObj = bucketObjects.map(buckObj => { ...buckObj, bucketKey: new Buffer(buckObj.bucketKy).toString('base64') }) ...` something like dat ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform each element of your array with a simple `forEach` iterator before sending the response.

```
const getObjects = async (req, res) => {
  ...
  const bucketObjects = bucket.body.items;
  bucketObjects.forEach(obj => obj.key = new Buffer(obj.objectKey).toString('base64'));
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
    bucketObjects,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use map function to return a new array.

```
const newArray = bucketObjects.map((object) => {
  return {
    ...object,
    objectKey: conversionToBase64(object.objectKey)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, this works fine but is there a way to also keep the original objectKey and return a newObjectKey?